# Column-wise autocomplete

Tags: postgresql, autocomplete

I have a table in a PostgreSQL database with four columns that contain increasingly more detailed information (think state->city->street->number), along with a column where everything is concatenated according to some simple formatting rules. Example:

```
| kommun     | trakt        | block | enhet | beteckning             |
| Mora       | Gislövs Läge | 9     | 16    | Mora Gislövs Läge 9:16 |
| Mora       | Gisslaved    | *     | 8     | Mora Gisslaved 8       |
| Mora       | Gisslaved    | *     | 9     | Mora Gisslaved 9       |
| Lilla Edet | Sanda        | GA    | 1     | Lilla Edet Sanda GA:1  |
```

A web service uses this table to implement a word-wise autocomplete, where the user gets input suggestions as they drill down. An input of `mora gis` will result in

```
["Mora Gislövs", "Mora Gisslaved"]
```

Currently, this is done by splitting the concatenated column by word in this query:

```
select distinct trim(substring(beteckning from '(^(\S+\s?){NUMPARTS})')) as bet
from beteckning_ac
where upper(beteckning) like upper('mora gis%')
order by bet
```

Where `NUMPARTS` is the number of words in the input - 2 in this case.

Now I want the autocomplete to be done column-wise rather than word-wise, so `mora gis` would now result in this instead:

```
["Mora Gislövs Läge", "Mora Gisslaved"]
```

Since the first two columns can contain an arbitrary number of words, I can no longer use the input to determine how many columns to include in the response. Is there a way to do this, or have I maybe gone about this autocomplete business all wrong?

Comment: you could split the input in multiple fields. For example you input in kommun something, you could autocomplete there, and so on..

Comment: @BenH Good idea. Unfortunately, there's only one input field in the client and that's out of my hands.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_auto(text)
--$1 is here your input
 RETURNS setof text
 LANGUAGE plpgsql

AS $function$
declare
  NUMPARTS int := array_length(regexp_split_to_array($1,' '), 1);
begin

return query 
 select
   case 
     when (NUMPARTS = 1) then kommun
     when (NUMPARTS = 2) then kommun||' '||trakt
     when (NUMPARTS = 3) then kommun||' '||trakt||' '||block
     when (NUMPARTS = 4) then kommun||' '||trakt||' '||block||' '||enhet
     --alter if you want to
   end
  from 
    auto_complete --your tablename here
  where 
    beteckning like $1||'%';
end;
$function$;
```

Comment: If I read this right, then I would still need to know beforehand how many columns are in play. From `mora gis` I wouldn't know if NUMPARTS should be 1 or 2. Can I run another query to determine that, perhaps?

Comment: (After edit) NUMPARTS is still just a word count. It will work for `mora gis`, but it won't work for `lilla ed`. In this case I would expect a result of `["Lilla Edet"]`